# Why BcdPrecision return value deducted by BcdScale?

Tags: delphi

In unit `Data.FmtBcd.pas`, `BcdPrecision` and `BcdScale` functions defined as:

```
function BcdPrecision(const Bcd: TBcd): Word;
begin
  Result := Bcd.Precision - BcdScale(Bcd);
end;

function BcdScale(const Bcd: TBcd): Word;
begin
  Result := (Bcd.SignSpecialPlaces and 63);
end;
```

and `TBcd` is declared as:

```
TBcd  = record
  Precision: Byte;                        { 1..64 }
  SignSpecialPlaces: Byte;                { Sign:1, Special:1, Places:6 }
  Fraction: packed array [0..31] of Byte; { BCD Nibbles, 00..99 per Byte, high Nibble 1st }
end;
```

Execute the following code would cause error:

```
var
  B, B1: TBcd;
  i1, i2: integer;
begin
  B := 530;
  i1 := BCDPrecision(B);    // return 3
  i2 := BCDScale(B);        // return 1
  Assert(NormalizeBcd(B, B1, i1, i2));
end;
```

`BCDPrecision(B)` return `3` (`B.Precision - 1`) and thus cause error.

If BCDPrecision(B) return `4` then it won't cause error.  Why would implementation of `BCDPrecision` deducted by `BCDScale` and not return `TBcd.Precision`?

Comment: Presumably because the precision field is relative to the scale, and BcdPrecision returns an absolute value.

Comment: Or perhaps vice versa.